# can we use sessions in cgridview to store the value obatined on cbuttoncolumn clicked

Tags: session, yii, cgridview, cbuttoncolumn

i need to know can we use sessions in cgridview to store the value obatined.

something like

in view

```
//  cgridview
    ..........
 ' name',
  array
 ('header'=>'ID',
 'value'=>'Yii::app()->SESSION['id']=$data["rid"]'),

 .......
```

this is my gridview

```
 <?php
 $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
 'dataProvider'=>$dataP10,
 'ajaxUpdate'=>true,
 'columns'=>array(

  array('name'=>' Name','value'=>'$data["name"]'),

 array('name'=>' createdate','value'=>'$data["createdate"]'),

  array(
 'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
 'template'=>'{view}',
 'buttons'=>array(

                    'view'=>array(
                        'url'=>'Yii::app()- >createUrl("controller/action",array("id"=>$data["id"]))',
                    ),
                ),
    ),

 ),

  ));
  ?>
```

here data["id"] i dont want it to be querystring but something in session for that particular record its id to be in session

```
      'view'=>array(
                        'url'=>'Yii::app()- >createUrl("controller/action",array("id"=>$data["id"]))',
                    ),
```

can anyone let me know can this  happen if so then do suggest your guidance

Comment: You can get this value from dataProvider which you pass in CGridView.
Use `$dataProvider->getData();` method.

Comment: Do you want to show session values in grid view? Or want to store rid in session?

Comment: @Oledje i have got the value $data["rid"] only thing is i need to know can i store it in session Yii::app()->SESSION['id']

Comment: @kumar_v  want to store rid in session ie.,...........Yii::app()->SESSION['id']=$data["rid"]

Comment: Of course it can be implemented as follows:
`'value'=>'Yii::app()->session["id"] = $data->rid'`
But it is somewhat ugly approach. You store in session["id"] only last row value as each successive value will overwrite the previous one.

Comment: @tisha if you store id in session for every record, you will get only last id. no use of it.

Comment: sorry for the late reply @Oledje  ya you are exactly correct. is their any way out like if i click on any cbuttoncolumn i can stored that particular value in session? am thinking of thats ..hope its possile but am unable to figure out exactly what next

Comment: sorry for the late reply @kumar_v  ya you are exactly correct. is their any way out like if i click on any cbuttoncolumn i can stored that particular value in session? am thinking of thats ..hope its possile but am uable to figure out exactly what next

Comment: @tisha "Session" variables stores on the server. Not on the client. You can send ajax request after clicking on table row and send any data to server and to store it there.

Comment: @Oledje i very well know that :) i dont want the id to be seen by user therefore using session to stored it in sesion and access throughout that session

Comment: If I understand correctly what you want, then this should help:
`Yii::app()->session["gridData"] = array();`
and further:
`'value'=>'Yii::app()->session["gridData"][$row] = $data->rid'`

Comment: @Oledje one of the solution l try and let you know

Answer (score 1):

Your grid definition is mystery to me !

What I think you need is sth like [this, ajax event on cbuttoncolumn](http://fugitiveink.org/cgridview-with-a-custom-cbuttoncolumn-that-submits-via-ajax/)

```
 array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
            'header'=>'Add',
            'template'=>'{add}',
            'buttons'=>array(
                'add'=>array(
                    'label'=>'Mark It',                        
                    'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("Controller/markIt", array("id"=>$data['id']))',
                    'options'=>array(
                        'ajax'=>array(
                            'type'=>'POST',
                            'url'=>'js:$(this).attr("href")',
                            'success'=>'function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                                var json = $.parseJSON(data);
                             }',
                            'error'=>'function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                                alert(errorThrown)
                            }',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
               'view'=>array(
                    'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("controller/view",array("id"=>$data["id"]))',
                ),
            ),
        ),
```

In the controller you have to define a function e. g

**Controller**

```
  public function markIt($id){
     if(Yii::app()->getRequest()->getIsAjaxRequest()) {
         $_SESSION['id']=$id;
     }
  }

public function view($id){
    //view records 
}
```

Now given your comments down I am puzzled , you want to click on the record and
    --> Add the respective record id to session
    --> View the record

If you need to perform both actions you just need to put this at the top of view funciton e.g
    `function view($id){
     //check if record found
     $_SESSION['id']=$id;
     ...
     reset of the code
    }`

else see above code where you have two buttons one to set the value to session other to view the record . You need to be clear about the flow of actions first .

Comment: sorry for the late reply n thanks,only last row value as each successive value will overwrite the previous one which is not what i need my need  is  if i click on any cbuttoncolumn i can stored that particular value in session? am thinking of thats ..hope its possile but am uable to figure out exactly what next

Comment: the click will be from the client side so , you have to setup an javascript event to send ajax request to put that to session

Comment: please share the whole grid definition

Comment: thanks have update my question with the grid .... can you please explain me.......this part of your code......'url'=>'js:$(this).attr("href")',
                            'success'=>'function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                                var json = $.parseJSON(data);
                             }',
                            'error'=>'function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                                alert(errorThrown)
                            }',    ............ am a bit not understanding

Comment: its sending ajax request to set the data to session when you click respective add or view button in the row . I assume that you don't want to view the record when you click [view] button

Comment: thanx for explaining :) but then i do want to view the record

Comment: want i think is l call the actionview in actionmarkit what say ur views am yet to attempt it .i think it might work